# looking for camera support

Tags: scanner, camera

I have a "It"  film scanner camera (ITNS-500, model scnd503T1231), it shows up as a scanner, but I cant get it to communicate. in dmesg:

```
[23173.912666] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05a9, idProduct=35c1, bcdDevice= 1.00
[23173.912669] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[23173.912670] usb 3-3: Product: Film and Photo Scanner
[23173.912672] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: FW-OV550_09.12.15.1
```

from lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 05a9:35c1 OmniVision Technologies, Inc.
```

How can I get images out of this device?

Comment: What softwares have you tried?

Comment: Did you tried `scanimage -L`?